# Why is this Google Sheets Query getting a parse error

Tags: google-sheets

I am working on a query formula in google sheets.  I am trying to get the WHERE part of the query to end at the end of the last month.  I am getting a parse error at 'TEXT(EOMONTH(now(), -1),"yyyy-mm-dd")'. I know that is the portion that is failing because if I replace it with a date (2021-07-31) the query works.

Thanks in advance.

=QUERY(Transactions!A:Z, "
SELECT K, -1 * SUM(E)
WHERE F LIKE 'Investing'
AND B > DATE '2020-05-31'
AND B < DATE 'TEXT(EOMONTH(now(), -1),"yyyy-mm-dd")'
GROUP BY K
LABEL -1 * SUM(E) 'Investments'
FORMAT K          'yyyy-MMM',
-1 * SUM(E) '$#,##0.00'
")"))"

Comment: Might be easier if you posted sample sheet with only a couple rows of data

Comment: You've got several problems going on throughout that formula. As has been suggested above, it would be easier to eliminate those problems if we had access to a copy of your spreadsheet with some realistic data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more issues with your current formula than one. See my comment below your post. However, you can try this:

`=QUERY(Transactions!A:Z, "SELECT K, -1 * SUM(E) WHERE F LIKE 'Investing' AND B > DATE '2020-05-31' AND B < DATE '"&TEXT(EOMONTH(now(), -1),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' GROUP BY K LABEL -1 * SUM(E) 'Investments' FORMAT K 'yyyy-MMM', -1 * SUM(E) '$#,##0.00' ")`

If that does not work, share a copy of your sheet.

Additionally, it's not clear to me why you're referencing `A:Z` when your `QUERY` only requires `B:K`. This won't affect the return; but in larger sheets, requesting only what you need can speed up processing.

Comment: Yes, after seeing your code I see the other issues.  I am new to this.  This has worked and I am learning from what you have provided.  Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help. We were all new to this (whatever "this" is in life) at some point, and so we all essentially learn the same way: from scratch and one piece at a time.